# Add dependency to existing reactor project without modifying the existing project

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I am attempting to integrate a custom dependency to an existing reactor project in such a way that I don't have to touch the existing pom files.

The setup looks like this:

**Existing Project**

```
parent_project/
|-- pom.xml
|-- core_module/
| |-- {code}
| |-- pom.xml
|-- web_module/
| |-- {code}
| |-- pom.xml
```

When this project is built, the `web_module` pom file creates a jar with dependencies (this is a spring boot app).

I would like to add a custom plugin to this in order to provide an additional dependency to be packaged in the `web_module` jar **without** manually modifying the `parent_project/pom.xml`. The custom plugin would be auto-discovered using the `ServiceLoader` system. I'd like to package these all together in order to simplify the build system, although I do understand I could just build them separately and have the java command load the custom code on the classpath at runtime.

I can imagine something like:

```
parent_project/
|-- pom.xml
|-- core_module/
| |-- {code}
| |-- pom.xml
|-- web_module/
| |-- {code}
| |-- pom.xml
|-- custom_plugin/
| |-- {code}
| |-- pom.xml
```

But I don't know how to integrate the `parent_project/custom_plugin/pom.xml` into the existing reactor without manually modifying the `modules` definition in the parent pom.

I can also imagine:

```
custom_plugin/
|-- {code}
|-- pom.xml
parent_project/
|-- pom.xml
|-- core_module/
| |-- {code}
| |-- pom.xml
|-- web_module/
| |-- {code}
| |-- pom.xml
```

But again I don't know of a way to reference the `custom_plugin` such that it is included in the `web_module` jar.

Is this possible? or do I have to just use the java runtime classpath way?

Comment: Sorry but the simple answer to this: `.. without modifying the existing project` is not possible. ???

Comment: That's my fear, but I'm hopeful someone knows a way to use/abuse the maven inheritance model or some dependency-based craziness.

Comment: Why is it a problem to change pom files if you need to implement a requirement?

Comment: well primarily because it isn't my project. The idea is that I'd like the system to have a separation of duties. the main project can iterate and grow on its own schedule, while my plugin code will likely stay roughly the same. I'd like to be able to re-build, including my code, but without messing around with the base project

Comment: Plugin code? Unfortunately it doesn't make it clearer to me?